# i would like to make a simple program that prevents the textbox to input duplicate data into the DataGridView

Tags: c#, visual-studio, exception, error-handling

i would like to make a simple program that prevents the textbox to input duplicate data into the DataGridView

[here is the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9eps8.png)

```
 private void cekId(Kelola kel1)
    {
        if (txtId.Text == dgvRole.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value.ToString())
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < dgvRole.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                if (txtId.Text == dgvRole.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value.ToString())
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Data ID Yang Anda Masukkan Sudah Ada Di Dalam DataGrid");
                    return;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Your first if statement references i which is not defined until the for loop. Simply delete the outer if and it should run.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before using `i`, it should be declared. So as Jonathan Willcock said, you just need to delete the outer `if statement`.

In addition, need to check if the last line is blank.

If you add data to the DataGridView manually, modify the code like this.

```
for (int i = 0; i < dgvRole.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
{
    if (txtId == dgvRole.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value.ToString())
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Data ID Yang Anda Masukkan Sudah Ada Di Dalam DataGrid");
        return;
    }
}
```

If bind the DataGridView with DataSource, try to set the property `AllowUserToAddRows` of DataGridView to `false`.

```
dgvRole.AllowUserToAddRows = false;
```